# How to pick action to execute based on objects instanceof?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have some Implementations of class `Base`, and all objects are collected in a `List<Base>`.

How can I call a specific `action` based on the `instanceof` these objects, without having to use verbose `instanceof` checks? How could I pick a servicemethod to be executed based on the instance of these objects, but without having to care which object the action is executed on. The right service-method should be picked somehow automatically without typecasing or instanceof checks.

```
class Base;
class Foo extends Base;
class Bar extends Base;

class Service {
    List<Base> bases;

    public void someMethod() {
        for (Base base : bases) {
            //perform some instanceof dependend action.
            //these actions cannot be inside of any Base class as it makes use of other objects too.
            if (base instanceof Foo) {
                fooService.action((Foo) base);
            }
            if (base instanceof Bar) {
                barService.action((Bar) base);
            }
        }
    }
}


//custom service methods
class FooService {
    void action(Foo foo) {
    }
}

class BarService {
    void action(Bar bar) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This smells of an anti-pattern. Could strategy pattern work better here with less use of the brittle instanceof?

Comment: Or use some sort of factory to load the service methods.

Comment: Well, for a `strategy` I'd first have to know which instance of `Base` I'm working on, right? Cause I'd end up with a `FooStrategy` and a `BarStrategy`, and if I want to call the `FooStrategy` on all `Foo` instances, I'd though have to do the `instanceof` check first...

Comment: Your comment "//these actions cannot be inside of any Base class as it makes use of other objects too." is not clear.  The fact that the action "makes use of other objects" doesn't mean it can't be inside your subclasses.  If polymorphism won't handle your case, then we (or at least I) don't understand your case, and more explanation is needed.  Can you explain better why polymorphism cannot be used?

Comment: Let's think of `Foo`, `Bar` as domain objects. The action that is to be executed is a `delete()` action. Depending on the instanceof the Base objects, different actions shall be executed on delete (eg cascading cleanup with different objects, deleting the object in different lists that are and should not be known by the domain object). Thus, I cannot/don't want to move such code into the domain objects, and could therefore not use polymorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymorphism is one possibility. If the Base class contains an abstract action() method, you could call it directly, without any if statements.

Another is a registry. For each subclass of Base you could register a mapping to a service class. In someMethod(), look up the class in the registry, get the corresponding service class, and call it.

By the way, verbosity is not the only problem with the instanceof statements. Code you write with these can break as soon as a new subclass of Base is created. Satisfying the [Open/Closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) can result in less fragile code.

Comment: Yes, but as written above, I cannot have the `action()` inside my Base classes, as it will be more of a service method that also makes use of other objects. It would otherwise be easy with Polymorphism, but I'm looking for a way to handle this without having to place the logic in the `Base` implementations.

Comment: Have you considered the second possibility - a registry?

Comment: Yes probably that's the only way I could go for, though I don't really feel comfortable with a registry lookup. It too doesn't feel right from the design point of view. Then it would probably be better to change the `Base` objects and introduce a `getService()` method, so that every implementation is forced to provide it's own service.

Comment: A registry could also be done *without* modification of the Base classes. For example, you can have a registry from data types to user-interface elements, without coupling the data layer to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use the `Visitor` pattern. You will need to combine `FooService` and `BarService` into a single class with both overloaded `action()` methods. Then you need to add a `accept()` method to each of the `Foo` and `Bar` classes which then can call the appropriate `action()` method. For more details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern.

There are possibly other, more appropriate [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) which can solve this problem. I suggest you study up on them.

Comment: OK thats nice, but: what if I have like 5 of these instance-specific methods? This would mean I'd have to write 5 Visitors then, and a new Visitor for each new instance-dependent behavior.

Comment: @member By "instance-specific" methods, do you mean 5 methods in each Service class? If so, then you will almost certainly need to use a different design pattern. I'm sure with a little research you can find something that will fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, like let's say I have some `add(), delete(), modify(), update()` methods. Each of them should be instance-dependent, which means `add()` for a `Foo` should be different than `add()` for a `Bar`. Anyway I want to keep all `Base` objects in a `List<Base>` and just execute `add(base)` by iteration on the list... Do you have a suggestion for a better design. Cause, as I'm asking here, I did not came up with a better one myself so far...

Comment: @membersound I suggest you start with the design pattern link which I gave in the answer or see what others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I ever got to solve this problem is:

```
class Base{};
class Foo extends Base{};
class Boo extends Base{};
```

Additional BaseService interface so every service class use the same methods:

```
public interface BaseService<T extends Base> {

void action(T base);

}
```

BooService:

```
public class BooService implements BaseService<Boo> {

public void action(Boo boo){
    System.out.println("Action performed by BooService");
    }
}
```

FooService:

```
public class FooService implements BaseService<Foo> {

public void action(Foo foo){
    System.out.println("Action performed by FooService");
    }
}
```

Additional ServiceSupplier class that will invoke proper Service base on passed object:

```
public class ServiceSupplier {

private Map<Class<? extends Base>, BaseService> services;

public ServiceSupplier(){
    initializeServiceMap();
}

public BaseService getServiceOfType(Class<? extends Base> clazz){
    return services.get(clazz);
}

private void initializeServiceMap() {
    services = new HashMap<>();
    services.put(Foo.class, new FooService());
    services.put(Boo.class, new BooService());
    }
}
```

And your Service class:

```
public class Service {
List<Base> bases;
ServiceSupplier serviceSupplier;

public Service(){
    serviceSupplier = new ServiceSupplier();

    bases = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Foo(), new Boo()));
}

public void someMethod() {
    bases.forEach(base -> serviceSupplier.getServiceOfType(base.getClass()).action(base));
    }
}
```

May seem much as just for removing few "if" statements but having more services all you need to do is add them to    `initializeServiceMap()` method.